# How do I convert datacolumn values to decimals for use in a chart?

Tags: c#, charts

This is what I am trying to do:

```
chart1.Series["ser1"].Points.AddY(database1DataSet.DataTable1.MyColumn);
```

However:
Series data points do not support values of type System.Data.DataColumn only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.

How do I convert to these types from a dataset. Forgive me if this is obvious, just started learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large datatable I would iterate through the rows as follows and add the points to your chart in the loop (i.e. there is no way to add the whole column as you have tried to do....each point has to be added seperately)

```
        using (var reader = database1DataSet.DataTable1.CreateDataReader())
        {
            int colOrdinal = database1DataSet.DataTable1.Columns["YourColumnName"].Ordinal
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                chart1.Series["ser1"].Points.AddY(reader.GetInt32(colOrdinal));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have more than one row inside your DataTable, I guess a way would be this one:

```
//loop through the rows of your DataTable 
foreach(DataRow row in database1DataSet.DataTable1)
{   //convert the value of each row before adding it
    chart1.Series["ser1"].Points.AddY(Convert.ToInt32(row["name of your column here"]));
}
```

In this case I converted the value into an Int32, but you can cast in any other you want, take a look at the documentation of the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class.